# Show categories in file module listing in Controlpanel

Tags: categories, control-panel, files, zenbu

I'm looking to find a way to show associated categories when viewing lists of files within the file module in the control panel.

I know that Zenbu can show this information but it only works with Entries and not Files.

Does any know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any available hook or add-on for it. You will need to customize the EE's controller file Content_files and associate view file for it.